# Sass darken function not compiling the output hex color

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to create 10 dark and light shades out of two **primary** and **secondary** colors, I want them in css variables rather than sass variables, like this:

```
$colors: (
  primary: #e32249,
  secondary: #0969a2
);

:root,
#root {
  @each $name, $color in $colors {
    --color-#{$name}: #{$color};

    @for $i from 1 through 10 {
      --color-#{$name}-dark-#{$i}: darken(#{$color}, calc(#{$i} * 10%));
      --color-#{$name}-light-#{$i}: lighten(#{$color}, calc(#{$i} * 10%));
    }
  }
}
```

Pretty simple, however the compiled css for `darken` function is not the new hex code, It's just the `darken(...)` function itself, and they just don't work... like is:

[image]

am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interpolate the whole value like `#{darken(...)}` because otherwise the SCSS transpiler will think it is a CSS value, thus ignoring it.

At the same time, remove interpolation inside the `darken` function because it is not needed.

Also, remove the `calc()` too because SCSS will automatically calculate the value. Use `calc` only when you need CSS to calculate the value.

```
$colors: (
  primary: #e32249,
  secondary: #0969a2
);

:root,
#root {
  @each $name, $color in $colors {
    --color-#{$name}: #{$color};

    @for $i from 1 through 10 {
      --color-#{$name}-dark-#{$i}: #{darken($color, $i * 10%)};
      --color-#{$name}-light-#{$i}: #{lighten($color, $i * 10%)};
    }
  }
}
```